# Recover contacts from Nexus 5 on terminal

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I've connected a Nexus 5 with no display to a Ubuntu laptop, and after installing mtpfs I can browse through the internal memory using Nautilus.

In the terminal, I believe the mount point should be at `/run/user/$$$/gvfs`, but I can't access the gvfs folder. It looks like:

```
d????????? ? ?      ?        ?            ? gvfs
```

I've tried changing chmod permissions but that didn't work.

My goal is to backup all the contact information an other profile data. Where is the database stored and how can I gain access to it?

Comment: MTP isn't going to give you access to the contacts database. Is the phone rooted?

Comment: the phone is unrooted; I can see I don't have access to any DB... in the android folder there are other app files